# Pandas Dataframe convert string to date without time

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe df:

```
a     date
1     2014-06-29 00:00:00
```

df.types return:

```
 a    object
 date object
```

I want convert column data to data without time but:

```
df['date']=df['date'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```

return:

```
a   date
1   2014-06-28 22:00:00
```

df.types return:

```
 a    object
 date datetime64[ns]
```

But value is wrong.

I'd have:

```
a     date
1     2014-06-29
```

or:

```
a     date
1     2014-06-29 00:00:00
```

Comment: Does `df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_cal['date'])` work? also you can just drop the time portion by doing `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())`

Comment: I already try a solution like yours but the error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'`.

Comment: It means they are strings so you need to either trim the hour portion off or convert to a datetime and then access the date() function. So for a string do `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[11:])` should work

Comment: Error now is  `can't compare datetime.date to str`

Comment: Sorry has this been converted to a datetime now or is a string, it's really unclear your question

Comment: Hi Ed. I have to convert a string (object type for a pandas dataframe) to date without time

Comment: Once you've converted to a datetime using `pd.to_datetime()` then do `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())` should work

Comment: Works.Thanks a lot. Sorry but i forget to convert string to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by putting your dates in pd.datetime:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

Now, you can see that the time component is still there:

```
df.date.values

array(['2014-06-28T19:00:00.000000000-0500'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

If you are ok having a date object again, you want:

```
df['date'] = [x.strftime("%y-%m-%d") for x in df.date]
```

Here would be ending with a datetime:

```
df['date'] = [x.date() for x in df.date]
df.date

datetime.date(2014, 6, 29)
```

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)` works. `df['date'] = [x.strftime("%y-%m-%d") for x in df.date] ` give error `can't compare datetime.date to str`

Comment: I think the OP was a little confused as to what needed to be done, the following worked for him :`df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.date())` you can add this to your answer, the OP should then accept it in my opinion

Comment: I agree. There are many ways to handle dates. The reason for the error @franco_b describes is that it must be passed a datetime, not an object. Run

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

to make it a datetime and then then

df['date'] = [x.strftime("%y-%m-%d") for x in df.date]

will work.

Comment: note that `x.strftime()` time requires `year > 1900`. If you are analyzing historic data, this won't work

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Just use this pattern:

df.to_datetime().date()